# Redirect files by extension with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site hosted in a Windows Server that contains a WP install and a bunch of custom ASP pages. I have to move the whole site to a new Linux host and the ASP pages to a subdomain in a Windows Server.

I need a .htaccess script to redirect the *.asp files to a subdomain, for example, http://www.domain.com/pagex.asp?id=12345 to http://windows.domain.com/pagex.asp?id=12345

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(.+\.asp)$ http://windows.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can test your rules here:

[htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

I tested the above rule with your example url (http://www.domain.com/pagex.asp?id=12345), and it returned your example result (http://windows.domain.com/pagex.asp?id=12345).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm afraid that it doesn't work. I've tested on a similar scenario. If the dummy asp exists I get the content and if the dummy aso doesn't exist I get a 404.

Comment: Since you are using an `.htaccess` file, do you have `AllowOverride` enabled for `RewriteRule` in the relevant `<Directory>` in your Apache config?

Comment: Also ensure `RewriteEngine` is `On`. Note added above.

Comment: Also, the leading `/` might have been the issue, so I made it optional. See [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27118/when-is-the-leading-slash-needed-in-mod-rewrite-patterns).

Comment: Yes. I've tested with AllowOverride "All" and "None" with no luck. I'll keep testing.

Comment: `AllowOverride` would need to be `All` or `FileInfo`. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: I just tested the rule above [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it worked.